# Can't get my azure sql server up and running

Tags: mysql, database, azure

I'm getting crazy over this issue, I hope someone can help me:

1. I created an Azure Database for MySQL server
2. Disabled SSL, and allowed all IPs to access
3. Trying to connect to the server using Server name and Server admin login name

I tried MySQLWorkbench, and CLI `mysql -u <Server admin login name> -h <Server name> -P 3306 -p`

In both cases it freezes, no error messages, doesn't timeout, no logs on the azure side.

I have literally no idea what's wrong or what to do about it. The database was just created, totally untouched.

Has anyone experiences something similar before?

Thank you!

Comment: When you followed these steps that should work: [Quickstart: Create an Azure Database for MySQL server using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-cli)

Comment: Check azure firewall om database server since it is by default enabled.

Answer (score 0):

With the given information it's not clear what is the exact error while accessing the database, but if you have deployed it properly you can access it easily without any error using both, MySQL Workbench and CLI.

In your example, the sequence of parameter isn't in write format which might giving issue.

Try below format:

`mysql -h <server_name>.mysql.database.azure.com -u <admin_name>@<server_name> -p`

If using MySQL Workbench, you can refer official document [Use MySQL Workbench to connect and query data in Azure Database for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-workbench) for the same.

This should work.